# Using Siteimprove Accessability Checker after converting PHP file to HTML does not work

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, accessibility

I have some PHP files, my IT department wants to perform accessibility checks on these files, but they said that these files need to be converted to HTML first before they run the checker on them.

Now, I loaded the pages in browser and save them as HTML, but what happens is that the accessibility checker extension which is installed on Chrome (Siteimprove Accessability Checker), does not work anymore. It only works on the PHP files that I see in my browser.

Has anyone had a similar experience? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: You need to use a web server (e.g. Apache, Nginx). You can't just open the PHP files directly in your browser.

Comment: _"It only works on the PHP files"_ - what does the checker do if you load the html file instead?

Comment: @Jeff, it does not show me any suggestions. It is like the extension does not work.

Comment: @Mike , I am using Apache; I do not have any problems when run this extension on the PHP files that I see through my browser. Just when I save the page as HTML and run the extension again, it does not provide me with any feedback

Comment: Open your developer console, are there errors?

Comment: Chrome extensions that do not have the [`chrome.fileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) permission will not be able to read local files. This is a security feature, not a bug.

Comment: Why not just run the extension on the PHP file and save the output HTML as a `.html` file and send that to your IT department?

Comment: @Mike that's what I did. But since I checked the local files with the extension and did not see any feedback, though there is something wrong with files!

Comment: @nina_dev The Chrome extension (or even your web browser) has no idea of whether the original file was parsed with PHP, ASP, Java, Ruby, etc. or even plain HTML. What it sees is are the HTTP headers sent by the server and the output (HTML in this case). That's it. So if the output passes whatever accessibility tests when being parsed with PHP it will be exactly the same when it's a plain HTML file.

Comment: Which extension do you use?

Comment: @unor, Siteimprove Accessability Checker